# CSS - How to make a 100% height div not overlap it's contents when window is resized

Tags: html, css

I've got 3 divs all take 100% height to create the block scroll effect. One of these divs has got text inside it. The problem is when i resize the window width the text starts overlapping from the bottom. I'd like the div height to stretch even more to not let overlapping happpen.
Code(HTML):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="company" id="company">
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Carousel indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>   
            <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="/dev/images/example.png" alt="First Slide">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Caption title 1</h3>
                        <p>Caption text 1</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="/dev/images/example.png" alt="Second Slide">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Caption title 2</h3>
                        <p>Caption text 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="/dev/images/example.png" alt="Third Slide">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Caption title 3</h3>
                        <p>Caption text 3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Carousel controls -->
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1>Dynavio</h1>
            <p>Dynavio is a company, which specializes in automation.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut fringilla dignissim ex. Curabitur eu purus non turpis consequat gravida et ut velit. Praesent semper orci est, vel rutrum enim laoreet sed. Donec commodo velit in elit viverra aliquam. Mauris accumsan lorem ante, ut elementum massa vestibulum vitae. Quisque faucibus, lorem quis vulputate tincidunt, sapien mi volutpat dui, nec interdum nisl elit ut turpis. Integer consectetur dui volutpat justo volutpat, ut rhoncus arcu accumsan. Sed aliquet venenatis felis, vitae feugiat nibh venenatis vel. Sed id dui quis odio suscipit rutrum at vel velit.</p>
            <h1>Members</h1>
            <img src="/dev/images/olanigan.jpg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Ibrahim Olanigan" class="img-circle member-image cursor-pointer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code(CSS):

```
.wrapper {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.company {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r90sdk6g/

Comment: CSS you provided is not enough to produce issue. Better way add fiddle.

Comment: You can  use `min-height` attribute, to stop `<div>` from shrinking after some point.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: i did, refresh the page. I also noticed content wasn't height 100% in the jsfiddle.

Comment: In your fiddle, the overlap is removed by setting the following: `body, p { margin: 0; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was surprisingly easy i just needed to remove `height: 100%;` from `.company`.